# Trouble in displaying Blob image stored in oracle db (using hibernate) on jsp in struts 1.3 framework

Tags: encryption, oracle11g, base64, blob, struts-1

I have stored an image in oracle database as BLOB type (using hibernate not jdbc). I have also retrieved the image and stored it in byte array, now I want to display the same on jsp page as an image. Framework I am using is struts 1.3

I have encoded the image bytes (Base64 encoding) and converted the same in string.

```
byte[] imageInBytes = siteService.getImageInBytes(parameter);
        reponse.setContentType("image/png");
        siteInfoManagementForm.setLogo(base.encodeBase64(imageInBytes));
        siteInfoManagementForm.setByteArrayString(siteInfoManagementForm.getLogo());
```

In form class:

```
public void setByteArrayString(byte[] bs) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    this.byteArrayString = new String(this.logo, "UTF-8");
}
```

When I write that string on jsp page, it is not converted into the image. Code written on jsp:

```
<html:img src="data:image/png;base64,${siteInfoManagementForm.byteArrayString}"/>
```

Please guide me further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(b);
String base64DataString = new String(encodeBase64 , "UTF-8");
```

In jsp..

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,[the value of your base64DataString]"
```

Comment: I have done the same, when I upload image from jsp and store it in oracle database and immidiatly display on jsp, it works fine. But when after closing that session when I fetch the same image from database(instead of uploading from jsp), image bytes changes which gives ultimately corrupted image.

Comment: The issue has been solved, what I did is instead of using existing hibernate connection I took new jdbc connection and wrote sql query to insert BLOB.